# If we select all checkbox manually how to get selected selectAll checkbox in jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to do it?
i can do this

```
<input type='checkbox' id='selectAll'/>
<input type='checkbox' id='select1' class='select'/>
<input type='checkbox' id='select2' class='select'/>
```

jquery to select all when `#selectAll` checked

```
    $('#selectAll').click(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $(".select").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(".select").prop("checked", false);
    }                
});
```

how to do it in reverse? if I checked `#select1` and `#select2` then `#selectAll` get checked automatic.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of shorter code could work as expected.

```js
$('#selectAll').click(function() {
  $(':checkbox.select').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
$(':checkbox.select').click(function() {
  $('#selectAll').prop('checked', $(':checkbox.select').length === $(':checked.select').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='selectAll'/>
<input type='checkbox' id='select1' class='select'/>
<input type='checkbox' id='select2' class='select'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this

```
$('checkbox').click(function(){
    if($("#select1").prop("checked") && $("#select2").prop("checked")) {
        $("#selectAll").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $("#selectAll").prop("checked", false);
    }                
});




   $('checkbox').click(function(){
let n = number_of_checkboxes; // can be any number
let checked = 0;
for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
if($("#select" + "'i'").prop("checked"){
checked = checked + 1; // use parseInt if required
}
}

if(checked == n){
$("#selectAll").prop("checked", true);
}
else {
 $("#selectAll").prop("checked", false);
}
        });
```

Comment: If you have more checkboxes, you can make it dynamic too.

Comment: In that case, you need to determine the number of checkboxes and use that inside click function.

Comment: in case of dynamic, you can play with second function to get your results. Logic will be to check any checkbox click event and manipulate all. Keep the  id in sync like select1,select2...selectn